# Matching words in string regardless of what comes in between

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-matching

I'm looking to check if all "do" "drugs" are in the string in the same frequency and in order regardless of what comes in between.

For example it should match:

```
"Everyone go do drugs"

"Everyone go d[o] dru]gs!"

"Everyone go do[heyyo]dr--ugs"
```

Regex doesn't seem like the right way to go. How should I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with just regex if you want to avoid false positives like 'today our driver urgently reminded us to pay our bills.`, so you'd need slightly more complicated rules than 'this string, regardless what comes between it'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this regex do what you want?

```
/^.*d.*o.*d.*r.*u.*g.*s.*$/i
```

Using this regex you can variate the number of symbols between

```
/^.*d.{0,10}o.{0,10}d.{0,10}r.{0,10}u.{0,10}g.{0,10}s.*$/i
```

Take a look at https://regex101.com/ if you didn't meet it before. It's a great place to learn and experiment

Comment: `/^.*d.*o.*d.*r.*u.*g.*s.*$/i.test( 'today our driver urgently reminded us to pay our bills' )` is true.

Comment: But that looks like it matches the spec.  Isn't that essentially what was requested?

Comment: Yes, because of "toDay Our DRiver UrGently reminded uS to pay our bills". Than concretize what you mean by "regardless of what comes in between"

Comment: Is there any way to match only if the characters are not more than 10 spaces apart?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to first remove all special characters in the `string` before checking for your `regex`:

1. Use `.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')` to remove all special characters from your `string`.
2. Use [`/do.+drugs/`](https://regex101.com/r/h4NKQO/1) as  a regex to check if the string matches your desired pattern.

**Demo:**

```js
let inputs = ["Everyone go do drugs",
  "Everyone go d[o] dru]gs!",
  "Everyone go do[heyyo]dr--ugs"
];

inputs = inputs.map(i => i.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''));

inputs.forEach(i => {
  console.log(i + ":   " + i.match(/do.+drugs/));
});
```